# Использование imageList для toolStripButton ещё актуально?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop

Вообще, возникло несколько вопросов.

1. Если использовать imageList для назначения иконок кнопкам toolStripButton, является ли это "хорошим тоном" или это устаревшая практика?
2. При назначении изображения (image.png) кнопке toolStripButton через интерфейс конструктора, изображение на кнопке в runtime выглядит красиво, гладко.
   Если же изображение назначить в коде:

   ```
    toolStripButton1.Image = imageList_x32.Images[0];
   ```

то в runtime изображение на кнопке получается "пикселизированное", грубоватое, видны резкие переходы между оттенками цвета.

Как это можно исправить, если всё же использовать imageList?

3. Как лучше поступить, если понадобиться динамически изменять размер изображений на кнопках, например, переключиться с 16x16 на 32x32 ?